# _tkinter.TclError: image doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I know this question has been asked quite often, but I still can't figure out what's the problem:

I'm trying to make a simple Tkinter window with 4 Buttons. Each one should have a background Image. When I try to set `image=path+'image.png'` I get this: `_tkinter.TclError: image "C:/Users/.../image.png" doesn't exist`. The strange thing is that when I copy the path from the message and paste it into the Explorer adress line it opens the image i want to have as background image.

Here's the necessary code:

```py
import tkinter

global path
path = 'C:/Users/Michael Hofmann/.../kahoot' 

root = tkinter.Tk()
Button_red = tkinter.Button(root, image=path+'/images/red_small.png', command= pressed('red'))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you an *image object* doesn't exist by that name, not that a *file* doesn't exist by that name. The `image` option requires an object of type `tkinter.PhotoImage`. You can't just give it a path to an image.

```
image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=path+'/images/red_small.png')
Button_red = tkitner.Button(..., image=image)
```